# SQLiteDataReader pick up one field from the next record?

Tags: vb.net, sqlite

With a sql like this

```
Dim sql = "SELECT * FROM TablePDF order by NameX asc"
```

I loop through the names of my database and make a iTextsharp table with the data.

```
While (readerProtocoloTablePDF.Read())

NameXPDF = (readerProtocoloTablePDF("NameX"))
...
...
...
```

If the records looks like

Audi

Alfa Romeo

Aston Martin

BMW

Bugatti

**When I read "Aston Martin" I need to know this is THE LAST NAME starting with "A" so the row of this record will have a special bottom line to close the A letter**

This is because I need to change the border or the cell of the last record and insert a blank page before the start of the new letter

The options are

```
cellHRectangleBorder = 12 'just left and right border
cellHRectangleBorder = 14 'lef, right AND BOTTOM border (Last record of a letter)
```

On the table I use code like

```
cellH3.Border = cellHRectangleBorder
```

And if it is the last record of a letter also I need a blank page

```
pdfDoc.NewPage()
```

I know how to detect the change of the letter while reading BMW, but this is AFTER the A ended.

**Is there a way to just pick up one field of the next record without breaking the normal sql reader?**

Or I need one loop inside another or maybe first a While - reader loop just to detect when a letter change and then another While reader loop to create the table knowing from beforehand the numbers of fields with each letter?

Comment: What is the problem in adding your special line when you read BMW but BEFORE adding the line with BMW to your PDF? Probably if you give more context around your code above we can suggest an alternative

Comment: @Steve more code added. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can only suggest a pseudocode that you should transform in your actual code with the real variable names, but essentially you don't add a line when you read it, but you add it on the following read

```vb
Dim lastName as String = ""
Dim lastLetter As string = ""
While (readerProtocoloTablePDF.Read())
    ' Read the Name and store it
    NameXPDF = (readerProtocoloTablePDF("NameX"))
    Dim curLetter = NameXPDF(0).ToString()

    ' Skip first loop
    if lastLetter <> ""  Then 
       ' After the first loop check if there is a change in the first letter
       if lastLetter <> curLetter then
           ' Yes, add the previous loop name as the last line and jump page
           AddTheLastLineOfThePage(lastName)
           NewPage()
       else 
           ' No add a normal line with the previous name read
           AddNormalLine(lastName)
       End if
    End if
    ' Save the current name read for the next loop
    lastName = NameXPDF
    lastLetter = lastName(0).ToString()
 Loop

 ' Do not forget to add the last line
 AddTheLastLineOfThePage(lastName)
```

Comment: Solved! Thanks to your pseudocode I found the solution. A graphic line to close the last record of the actual letter. So on the part "AddTheLastLineOfThePage(lastName)" I take the Y coord and knowing the left and right margin of my A4 PDF one line solved the problem.